# Why is this array undefined when I call .length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am working on an exercise from the book *[Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)* ([see 'a list' at bottom of linked page](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html)). Basically, I want to make an object that takes an array and turns it into a list with the following structure:

```
var list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};
```

When I run the code below in the console, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 3 in function arrayToList)`. Why is the array on which I am calling .length not defined?

```
function arrayToList(array){
    var list = {};
    if(!array.length){
        list.value = null;
    }
    else{
        list.value = array.shift();
        list.rest = arrayToList();
    }
    return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

**Note:** Stack Overflow question *[List data structures in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231056)* is a very similar post on the same problem. I'm not looking for a *solution* here so much as an explanation as to what is going haywire in the recursive call.

Comment: one idea: the function arrayToList() needs an array as an argument.  In the recursive calls, it isn't getting that argument...

Comment: Try tracing the function in a debugger.

Comment: Note that the error doesn't say that `.length` is undefined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
list.rest = arrayToList();
```

Since you don't pass any parameter to `arrayToList`, `array` will have the default value `undefined`. That is why it is failing with

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of ***undefined***

So, during the recursive call, you are supposed to pass an array to `arrayToList`, again.

```
function arrayToList(array) {
    var list = {};
    if (!array.length) {
        list.value = null;
    } else {
        list.value = array.shift();
        list.rest = arrayToList(array);   // Pass the `array` after shifting
    }
    return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
# { value: 10, rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: null } } }
```

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
    list.rest = arrayToList();
```

… you recursively call the function but you don't specify an argument, so `array` becomes `undefined`.

It looks like you should just pass `array` again (which you have modified).

```
    list.rest = arrayToList(array);
```

[live demo](http://jsbin.com/quvuyecaye/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 2):

In the recursive `arrayToList` call, you're not passing anything as a parameter (!).

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayToList(array) {
    var list = {};
    if (!(array instanceof Array) || array.length == 0) {
       list.value = null;
    } else {
        list.value = array.shift();
        list.rest = arrayToList();
    }
    return list;
}
```