# Eloquent Javascript Chapter 4: arrayToList/listToArray Execise

Tags: javascript, arrays

[Question from eloquentjavascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html):

> Write a function arrayToList that builds up a data structure like the
>   previous one when given [1, 2, 3] as argument, and write a listToArray
>   function that produces an array from a list. Also write the helper
>   functions prepend, which takes an element and a list and creates a new
>   list that adds the element to the front of the input list, and nth,
>   which takes a list and a number and returns the element at the given
>   position in the list, or undefined when there is no such element.

Can anyone explain this answer without any jargon? 
I can only learn by instructions.

Here is what I came up with for arrayToList:
So start list null, create for loop decrementing and inside define "i" then return list.

```
function arrayToList(array){ //pass list as parameter
    var list = null; // don't know why we make it null
    for (var i=array.length-1; i>=0; i--)  // why -1 on the length?
        list = {value: array[i], rest:list}; //clueless
    return list;
}
```

what is `rest:list` inside the `list` object?

Comment: related: [List data structures in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24231056/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is `rest:list` inside the `list` object?

It creates a property `rest` in the object literal, and assigns to it the value of the variable `list` - before assigning that object to the variable `list`. Notice that this happens in a loop, so what it does is to take the old value and overwrite it with a new value that references the old value.

Just what you need to build that nested list structure.

> `var list = null; // don't know why we make it null`

That's the initial value, which will be placed at the "end" of the list. If the array is empty, it will be returned, if the array has one element it will become the `rest` property of the object that is returned. If the array has more than one element…

> why -1 on the length?

Because arrays are zero-indexed, i.e. their indices run from `0` to `length-1`. When we iterate backwards, we need this odd initial value and the  `i >= 0` comparison.

Answer (score 4):

The last comment by @eloquent need to be modified:

```
var arr1 = [10, 20, 30];

function arrayToList(arr) {
  var list = {};

 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    list.value = arr.splice(0, 1)[0];
    list.rest = (arr.length > 0) ? arrayToList(arr) : null;
 }

 return list;
}

console.clear();
console.log(  arrayToList(arr1) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function arrayToList(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(i == arr.length) {
     return obj.rest = null;
    }
    obj.value = arr.splice(0,1);
    obj.rest = arrayToList(arr);
  }
  return obj;
};

console.clear();
console.dir(arrayToList([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution with recursion:

```
function arrayToList([...arr], n = 0){
  return (n < arr.length) ? {value: arr[n], rest: arrayToList(arr, n + 1)} : null;
} 

function listToArray({...list}, arr = []){
  arr.push(list.value);
  return (list.rest != null) ? listToArray(list.rest, arr) : arr;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}

console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([10, 20, 30])));
// → [10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

> don't know why we make it null

Probably just to make it clear that the initialized value is `null` (as apposed to `undefined`). Assigning `null` is not necessary either way.

> why -1 on the length?

Because length is 1-based (array with 4 items has a length of 4) but indexing into an array is 0-base (array[0] returns the 1st item).

> clueless

This step is creating a nested list object. The first loop creates a list with a value at that array position, the second loop creates a wrapper list with a value at that position and a pointer to the previous list, and so forth.

Comment: Here is the answer to the whole thing https://gist.github.com/laichejl/32d98af04caa66bd195f I am completely confused last chaper we were learning basics now its extremely hard

Comment: Ahh, I see. I read it wrong at first glance. It's embedding the previous list each loop inside of the `rest` property. What would you like explained?

Comment: Oh so rest is just a name (key/value pair of object)? It can be anything right? Why does it equal list?

Comment: It's just an arbitrarily-named key, yes. It could be called something else. It's being used to contain a pointer to the last list so that the eventual `Object` being returned can be crawled in order to reconstruct the original Array.

Answer (score 0):

As a disclaimer, I wanna say that I am a newbie myself and I'm here to learn things and maybe help others by doing it. Here's how I understood that the second problem it's done.

> Also write a listToArray function that produces an array from a list.

The following code will work:

```
function listToArray(list) {
    let arr = [];
    for(; list !== null; list = list.rest) {
      arr.push(list.value);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

The list parameter will just hold the argument that will be inserted. In our case is: `{value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}`

Have in mind that the code in the Eloquent Javascript will make a list from an array with 3 elements `[10, 20, 30]`, but for this example, we'll just use a list made from 2 elements.

On execution, the code will do the following things:

**1st time(first loop):**

1. omit the initialization of the for loop(don't define any variable or
   do anything)
2. check if the list is not null - it's not, because at this moment
   list is equal to  `{value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}`
3. make list(the parameter of the function) to be equal to `list.rest`

   - remember that `.rest` is just a property of the object list and that it points to another object - it will point to `{value: 20, rest: null}` in our case

**2nd time(second loop):**

1. omit the initialization of the for loop(don't define any variable or
   do anything)
2. check if the list is not null - it's not, because at
       this moment list is equal to `{value: 20, rest: null}`
3. make list again to be equal to list.rest - but at this time it will
   point to `rest: null`, so this time the value of the list will be the
   value of the `rest` key, which is `null`

**3rd time(third loop):**

1. omit
2. check if the list is not null - it is in this case, so stop the
   execution and go to the return statement
3. return arr

My answer is based on: https://gist.github.com/laichejl/32d98af04caa66bd195f#file-exercise-js-L18

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming from Java background and don't understand why with the given in the book solution the end result is not just the last element of the given argument (array) but it actually created linked list?

```
list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
```

In my eyes, if you pass [1,2,3,4] as argument, then `value` will be sequentially equal to 1 then to 2, then to 3 and finally to 4, and there shouldn't be any links, but `rest` will point to the very same address as in the beginning, just now `value` will be equal to 4.
So how this works?

This is how the program will look in java terms:

```
public class Main {

    public class MyList{
   
        public int value;
        public MyList rest;
    }
   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main main = new Main();
        MyList myList = main.new MyList();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            myList.value = i;
            current.rest = myList;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.println("Value: " + myList.value + " obj. ref: " + myList.rest);
    myList = myList.rest;
}

Value: 4 obj. ref: Main$MyList@1d81eb93
Value: 4 obj. ref: Main$MyList@1d81eb93
Value: 4 obj. ref: Main$MyList@1d81eb93
Value: 4 obj. ref: Main$MyList@1d81eb93
Value: 4 obj. ref: Main$MyList@1d81eb93
```

To work properly, we need to create new object every time, so the for loop should look like:

```
MyList current = myList;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    MyList newList = main.new MyList();
    current.value = i;
    current.rest = newList;
    current = newList;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Value: 0 obj. ref: Main$MyList@1d81eb93
Value: 1 obj. ref: Main$MyList@7291c18f
Value: 2 obj. ref: Main$MyList@34a245ab
Value: 3 obj. ref: Main$MyList@7cc355be
Value: 4 obj. ref: Main$MyList@6e8cf4c6
```

So how `list` reinstantiates itself in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

A simplified solution and a cleaner approach

```js
function arrayToList(inputArray )  {
  if (!inputArray.length) {
    return null;
  }
  const [head, ...tail] = inputArray;
  return { value: head, rest: arrayToList(tail) };
}
```